# What is the EtherType of a BPDU frame sent by a switch which runs Spanning Tree Protocol

Tags: switch, ethernet, spanning-tree, protocol-theory

I want to know what is the EtherType field of a BPDU frame in various versions and variants of the Spanning Tree Protocol.

Comment: A quick Google search would give you the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Ethertype for Spanning-Tree protocol BPDUs - they are encapsulated in 802.3 Ethernet (rather than Ethernet II), and so the Ethertype field does not exist.

See [What is the difference between Ethernet II and 802.3 Ethernet?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/what-is-the-difference-between-ethernet-ii-and-802-3-ethernet) for more information